# Splitting a string into two and assigning to two char array

Tags: c, arrays, string, char

I have a string like:

```
my age is 22\r\n\r\n and I live in Rostock
```

and some other strings like:

```
I like to swim\r\n\r\n .Yesterday I competed with my 2 friends
```

Now I want to split a string by `\r\n\r\n` and have it associated with `buffer`. Here is what I am trying to do:

```
char buffer[500];
strcpy(buffer, "my age is 22\r\n\r\n and I live in Rostock");
char *p = buffer;
if((p = strchr(p,"\r\n\r\n"))) {
       p[strcspn(p,"tock")] = 0; // trying to slice until the end
}

printf("%s", p);
```

This gives me a warning as I try to compile saying `warning: passing argument 2 of ‘strchr’ makes integer from pointer without a cast` I could not understand what this meant.

Also what is good way to split this into 2 `char` buffers?

Comment: See [strchr](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strchr/).  2nd argument of `strchr` should be an `int`, not a `char *`.

Comment: Looks like you want [`strstr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strstr) instead.

Comment: @Amanda You can use strtok. The call of strchr is invalid/ The second argument shall be a character.

Comment: It's not necessary to copy substrings to another array if string is mutable.  For `"my age is 22\r\n\r\n and I live in Rostock"`, for example, you can have two `char *`s, one pointing to `'m'` and the other pointing to `' '`.  Overwrite `"\r\n\r\n"` or just the first `'\r'` with `'\0'`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`strchr` expects a mere **`char`** and not a string for its second parameter. So you can only pass it a single character.

In C a `char` is a single character and strings are null terminated char arrays.

What you want to do is probably:

```
char buffer[500] = "my age is 22\r\n\r\n and I live in Rostock";  // directly initialize the char array

const char sep[] = "\r\n\r\n";

char * p = strstr(buffer, sep);   // search the separator
if (p) {
    *p = '\0';                    // null terminate the first part
    p += strlen(sep);             // make p point to the start of the second part
    printf("%s - %s\n", buffer, p);
}
```

---

If you really need to purge the initial part from buffer and have it start at the second part, you could do:

```
for (char *dest = buffer; p<buffer+sizeof(buffer)-1;) {   // do not go past end of array
    *dest++ = *p++;
    if (*p == '\0') break;         // stop on first null
}
```

Comment: How does `buffer` point to just the first part? When does `buffer` get modified? I am a little confused. I understood the `p` part but did not understand how did `buffer `get the first part?

Comment: @Amanda: As I said, a string is a **null terminated** character array, meaning that it stops on first null character. After the `strstr` call, `p` points to the first `\r` in `buffer`. `*p = 0;` replace that character with a null, actually truncating the string beginning at `buffer`. The magic comes that an array automatically decays to a pointer to its first element when it is used as a pointer.

Comment: @Amanda: this kind of char pointer processing is not really a trick, but idiomatic C langage :-)

Comment: Is there a way, I can have the last part after `\r\n\r\n` inside `buffer`? I tried `strcpy(buffer, p)` but many times I see an error `ERROR: AddressSanitizer: strcpy-param-overlap: memory ranges  ..`

Comment: @Amanda: `p` points inside `buffer` and `strcpy` does not want to copy a buffer onto itself. It can be obtained *by hand* but it should be avoided unless you have a good reason for that. This would actually be tricky...

Comment: Okay. Would you know a way, where buffer gets the part after `\r\n\r\n`?

Comment: I want to reduce the buffer such that it contains only the part after `\r\n\r\n`

Comment: Looks like the edit snippet, duplicates the part after `\r\n\r\n`

Comment: And what do you really want to obtain? A char array has a position in memory. You can copy what you want at that position but you cannot move an array. On the other side, a pointer can point to various memory positions at different times so it can be moved to point elsewhere. Please read books and tutorials about the basics of C. I can ask precise questions but I cannot teach you everything about C through SO questions.